# iMacro cannot save extract value to file

Tags: imacros

I am trying to save EXTRACT variable data to text file by using iMacro. However, I show the EXTRACT variable with value. Please save this file as .js before you try on iMacros. Thank you.

Show EXTRACT variable value.

```
iimSet("EXTRACT", "abcde");
iimPlay("CODE: PROMPT {{EXTRACT}}");
```

Save EXTRACT variable value to abc.txt.

```
scmd = "CODE:SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=/Users/user1/iMacros FILE=abc.txt";
iimPlay(scmd);
```

Answer (score 3):

make it simple,since you are using javascript anyway, use javascript prompt like this

```
var ask=prompt("Please enter your name");
iimSet("ask",ask);
iimPlay("code: set !extract {{ask}}\nSAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=/Users/user1/iMacros FILE=abc.txt");
```